# How to install Odoo 9 in Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: cloud, odoo, digital-ocean

I have couple of droplets in digitalocean.com. Previously I was able to install Odoo 8 in my droplet. But recently Odoo 9 has released & I dont know how to install it. Can somebody please walk me through how to do it. My droplet is running on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit & Is Odoo 9 a stable version?

Comment: I got how to install it. No need to post answers.

Comment: would you mind sharing it with others?